# Running code igniter, several sites, one server, different timezones?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, timezone

I am using code igniter to power our site, but are not using the code igniter date library (just the default php Date),

We have several, sites on the same server,

they reside in

www-nz
www-au
www-us

because all these sites use the same php.ini I cannot use date.timezone.

So I was thinking, sweet as, Ill just use .htaccess `SetEnv TZ location` e.g `Pacific/Auckland`

But it is having no effect, I have a feeling that code igniter might be resetting the timezone somewhere...

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Did you try date_default_timezone_set() function of PHP?

Comment: Strange, wonder why you got downvoted? it might be better to ask this question on serverfault.  I do think .htaccess should have worked.  Code igniter functions  should be picking up what PHP is giving it.

Comment: @eyazici: We shouldn't have to, if we set it through the .htaccess file code igniter should be picking it up...

Comment: @Matt H: no idea, as far as I am aware this is not a bad question, I was thinking about asking it on serverfault, but then this doesn't so much seem to be a server issue, more I believe code igniter is overriding something.

Comment: @Hailwood I don't know whether Code Ignitor picks the TZ environment variable or not but it shouldn't have to.

Comment: @eyazici: what do you mean it shouldn't have to?

Comment: @Hailwood I mean, it doesn't have to retrieve TZ environment variable which is passed to PHP by web server (eg. Apache) and set the default time zone according to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date_default_timezone_set() is what I place the top of my index.php files in CodeIgniter.  However I've learned that setting everything to UTC and then making any time zone conversions on the client side will save you A LOT of headaches :)

Comment: `making any time zone conversions on the client side` javascript?

Comment: Well there are two ways to do it: literally on the client (e.g. javascript) or once the data is out of the db when the client has requested the data.  The main point is to do the conversions once the data is out of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set AllowOverride directive in the apache configuration?  it could be that the .htaccess file is being ignored.

The other thing is.  You should probably just run this in GMT or local time.
Timezone is a client locality thing, not server.  If required you should deal with the local time from the client perspective.

Comment: Yeah, AllowOverride is set to All, but because everything on these sites is relative to the said timezones, we need the times to be relative to the timezones, not the user!